# Web API ignores non-model body parameters; should throw error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In Web API v2 when you supply data in the POST body that are not part of the model, they are ignored by the framework. This is fine in most cases, but I need to check this and return an error response, so the user doesn't get unexpected results (he expects these wrong parameters to do something...).

So how do I check for this? The model will be null, but when the framework has parsed the data and returned a null-model, I can no longer access the body through Request.Content. So what options are there?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to derive your DTO class from DynamicObject. Check out my blog post: http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/detecting-extra-fields-in-asp-net-web-api-request/

Comment: Interesting solution. I would however like not to derive from a base class.